# R filter a large dataframe conditional on dates, using filter and pipes

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, filter, pipes-filters

I have a large dataframe and I want to select rows which satisfy condition on date columns. The dataframe is similar to this:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

curdate <- seq(as.Date("2000/1/1"), by = "month", length.out = 24)
expdate <- rep(seq(as.Date("2000/3/1"), by = "quarter", length.out = 12),2)
afactor <- rep(c("C","P"),12)
anumber <- runif(24)
df<-data.frame(curdate, expdate, afactor, anumber)
df$expdate[12]<-as.Date("2001-02-01")
```

I would like to get the rows which the month of the expiration date (expdate) is two months later than the month of current date (curdate). In this example, I should select these five dates (rows 1, 7, 12, 13 and 19):

```
curdate     expdate     afactor     anumber
2000-01-01  2000-03-01     C        0.6832251
2000-07-01  2001-09-01     C        0.2671076
2001-01-01  2000-03-01     C        0.2097065
2001-07-01  2001-09-01     C        0.9258450
2000-12-01  2001-02-01     P        0.4903951
```

First I used the following line for that:

```
df_select1 <- df %>% group_by(curdate, afactor) %>% 
  filter(month(expdate) == month(curdate)+2)
```

But it misses the cases when the month is November or December. For instance here, it misses the case when curdate is 2000-12-01. So I want to add a condition, to deal with these cases. I wrote:

```
 df_select2 <- df %>% group_by(curdate, afactor) %>% 
  if_else(month(curdate)<11,
    filter(month(expdate) == month(curdate)+2),
    filter(month(expdate) == month(curdate)-10))
```

but I get the following error: *`condition` must be a logical vector, not a `grouped_df/tbl_df/tbl/data.frame` object*.

I found the following solution, but there are certainly much shorter ways to do it:

```
df_select1 <- df %>% group_by(curdate, afactor) %>% 
  filter(month(curdate)<11) %>%
  filter(month(expdate) == month(curdate)+2)

df_select2 <- df %>% group_by(curdate, afactor) %>% 
  filter(month(curdate)>10) %>%
  filter(month(expdate) == month(curdate)-10)

df_select <- full_join(df_select1, df_select2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're importing lubridate, you probably should also make use of its functions for calculating with months. Those are a bit tricky obviously because they are not of equal lengths, why the base function difftime is not offering a monthly unit for example.

This would be a solution for your problem, without the if_else function:

```
df_select1 <- df %>% group_by(curdate, afactor) %>% 
  filter(expdate == curdate + months(2))
```

By the way, you're not running into problems as long as your data is always the first day in the respective month. You have to decide what should happen in the following cases though:

```
ymd("2019-08-31")+months(1)
ymd("2019-01-29")+months(1)
```

This leads to an NA for obvious reason. If this happens lubridate::add_with_rollback() could offer a solution, depending on your needs.

An edit after clarifying the question. If you're looking for those dates whose expdate is two months "later" compared to the curdate, in the specific sense that you're comparing only their months regardless of the year, a little modulo operation might help:

```
df %>% 
  filter(lubridate::month(expdate) == (lubridate::month(curdate)+2) %% 12)
```

Comment: It does not solve the problem. The issue is to deal with cases when curdate is in November or December. See my example.

Comment: Can you specify why that should not work? Be aware that my code is different from yours! expdate == curdate + months(2) does actually compare two dates. ymd("2019-11-01")+months(2) is equal to "2020-01-01" or am I not getting the problem?

By contrast, using month(ymd("2019-11-01")) + 2 obviously leads to the integer 13, which is not what you want.

Comment: My question was not well formulated. I have just edited it. I want to select the expdate which month is two months after the curdate. Your code selects three rows 1, 12 and 19 but I would like to select rows 7 and 13 in addition to 1, 12 and 19.

Comment: You're right, I did not get the question right. You can check my edit, if you want. A little modulo operation should solve the problem, right?

Answer (score 2):

You can add 2 months to `curdate` using the %m+% operator from `lubridate`:

```
df %>% 
  filter(months(expdate) == months(curdate %m+% months(2)))
```

This will take into account the variation in days by calendar month.

**Edit**
I've added the `months` function from base-R after the question was updated. The `month` function from `lubridate` could also be used.

Comment: It does not solve the problem. The issue is to deal with cases when curdate is in November or December. See my example.

Comment: @BertrandG checking your test data - it seems that only rows 1, 12, and 19 should be matched. That's the output my code generates.

Comment: My question was not well formulated. I have just edited it. I want to select the expdate which month is two months after the curdate. Your code selects three rows 1, 12 and 19 indeed. I would like to select rows 7 and 13 in addition to 1, 12 and 19.